# Error while loading shared libraries: librtmp.so.0

Tags: shared-library

This is my problem (Ubuntu 16.10): `librtmp.so.0 => not found`

and the error script

```
/home/amroemad/Desktop/Total War WARHAMMER/bin/TotalWarhammer: error while loading shared libraries: librtmp.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm totally new to Linux and Ubuntu, so i need your help.

Answer (score 6):

I've suffered the same issue. Open terminal and add the following line, this works for ubuntu x86_64.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.0
```